# "failed to open '/etc/gitconfig' - permission denied" when clone a repo with GitKraken

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I tried to clone a repo using GitKraken on Ubuntu, but it threw me an error **"failed to open '/etc/gitconfig' - permission denied"**.

So I think GitKraken software **needs to access a gitconfig file** to get things work, and it somehow **tried to access the one at `/etc/gitconfig` first** (which is locked - *I don't even know what "lock" mean*), so it threw the error. After googling, I found a solution sounds rational is to type `chmod 777 /etc/gitconfig` to give everyone (includes GitKraken) **the permission** to read/write to that config file. But after doing that, it still not work (permission denied), even after a reboot. **First attemption failed**. Maybe **it's not about permission**?

I then kept googling, then I knew that there are 3 types of config files for git, which are **local** (located in `.git/gitconfig`), **global** (in `~/.gitconfig`) and **system** (in `/etc/gitconfig`). Then I thought ***"aha, I could just delete the `/etc/gitconfig`, then Kraken will use `~/.gitconfig`"***. And yet after deleting `/etc/gitconfig`, it works *(I can clone my repo as expected)*. But I think it's just a **workaround**, I don't know what's the consequence of doing this (deleting system gitconfig). As I read in the [document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), it should **first read the local one, then global, then system** in order, so it should **only read `/etc/gitconfig` if only can't find one in `~/.gitconfig`**, am I right? Why it isn't the case here? Or does GitKraken deliberately setting to read the config file from `/etc/gitconfig` first instead of the above order?

Conclude, I deleted the system gitconfig `/etc/gitconfig` (by renaming it to `/etc/.gitconfig` btw). My question is what should I do now, did I solve my problem? If yet then now I don't fully understand what's going on, please can someone explain to me?

Thanks in advance.

**Error capture:**
[image: capture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a `git config --show-origin -l` to see all configuration files involved.

The [/etc/gitconfig is the system-wide configuration file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES), always read first.
A locked file generally means another process has kept an handle on it (usual with Windows, but you might be on Linux)

You can recreate it later, even with a minimal content, just to see if the issue persists:

```
[color]
        diff = auto
        status = auto
        branch = auto
        interactive = true
```

Apparently, from the comments, the issue was how GitKraken was installed:

- from  Ubuntu Software
- instead of [`gitkraken.com/download`](https://www.gitkraken.com/download)

The second method produces a GitKraken which won't be tripped by a locked `/etc/gitconfig`.

Comment: Thank you!! After reading your comment, I tried recreating `/etc/gitconfig` file with the content suggested above. But as typing `git config --show-origin -l` I only saw configurations from `~/.gitconfig` (none from `/etc/gitconfig`). After that, I tried cloning a project with GitKraken, it pop up the same error `/etc/gitconfig is locked`. One of my friends has used GitKraken too and it works just fine on his computer, he can clone projects even if there's `/etc/gitconfig`, so I guess it doesn't matter its existence, but somehow, showbody (likely me) has locked my "system gitconfig" file?

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn Are you on Windows? What version of Git do you have installed?

Comment: No, I'm on the Ubuntu 19.04, and my git version is 2.20.1

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn Can you, for testing, upgrade to Git 2.24? (https://askubuntu.com/a/500733/5470)

Comment: I did, now I'm on git 2.24, have tried rebooting and the error is still the same. Ah, one thing I have noticed that when I typed `cd /`, I saw a lock symbol on the left of directory `/` on my terminal. But if I try typing `cd ~`, there are no locks.

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn Is there a difference in the way GitKraken itself has been installed (compared to your friend's workstation)? And would the clone succeed when done in command line? (`git clone ...`)

Comment: I honestly don't remember the way I installed it, I guess **from Ubuntu Software**. I asked my friend how he installed it, he said from the [official website](https://www.gitkraken.com/download). I tried doing the same, install from the website, and then there was 2 GitKrakens on my computer when tap on "Show Applications", but when I opened "Ubuntu Software-Installed", I only saw one, I deleted what I saw. After that, everything just worked, I could clone repo, there was still `/etc/gitconfig`, still a "lock symbol" on my terminal. I guess the problem was **the way I installed the software**?

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn I suspect the installation method was the culprit, but I don't know exactly why. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn Maybe a `sudo dpkg --configure -a` would have helped (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/489643/comments/2)

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn You are most welcome. Glad you now have a working GitKraken!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem on 20.04.
Unfortunately the download from the gitkraken website was giving me a dependency error, so i had to use snap.
Tried removing and recreating the config, didn't work. Tried everything in the comments of the other answer, but wasn't able to resolve the problem.

Simply deleting /etc/gitconfig resolved it for me.