# Error: warning: unable to access '/etc/gitconfig': Permission denied, when cloning a GitHub repo via gh repo clone

Tags: github-cli

On Ubuntu 20.04, I installed the `gh` CLI tool via:

```
sudo snap install gh
```

Then, trying to `gh repo clone` a public repo resulted in the error:

```
Error: warning: unable to access '/etc/gitconfig': Permission denied
```

This happened via HTTPS, and SSH with freshly generated key. Related QAs like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58987213/4511978) point at the possibility of an issue with installation.

How to fix this, so I can have the closest thing to the good old *clone with SSH key?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Likely, the `snap` installation was encapsulated and somehow unable to access the GitHub config file. The simplest fix in this case was to **uninstall the CLI tool and reinstall it following the [official docs](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md)**:

```
# remember to logout from GH if you haven't done so...
gh auth logout
sudo snap remove gh
```

Now, on a new terminal (to refresh the snap-related environment variables), install via the following official steps (should work on any Debian-based system):

```
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gh
```

At this point we're all set. Authenticate via your favorite method (I chose HTTPS via browser), and cloning should work without issues:

```
gh auth login
gh repo clone <YOUR_REPO>
```

Hope this helps!
Cheers,
Andres